# pip cannot import name 'sysconfig'

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, импорт, pip

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Возникла внезапная ошибка на сервере

При попытке использовать команду pip - получаю следующее

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/moneyrocket/env/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main
  File "/home/moneyrocket/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from pip._internal import cmdoptions
  File "/home/moneyrocket/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/cmdoptions.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip._internal.index import (
  File "/home/moneyrocket/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 25, in <module>
    from pip._internal.download import HAS_TLS, is_url, path_to_url, url_to_path
  File "/home/moneyrocket/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 35, in <module>
    from pip._internal.locations import write_delete_marker_file
  File "/home/moneyrocket/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/locations.py", line 10, in <module>
    from distutils import sysconfig as distutils_sysconfig
ImportError: cannot import name 'sysconfig'
```

Полазив по форумам, узнал что ошибка в импорте https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/master/src/pip/_internal/locations.py#L10

Т.е команда `python3 -c "import sysconfig"` импортирует все отлично, но если я буду использовать `python3 -c "from distutils import sysconfig as distutils_sysconfig"`, то получу следующее:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'sysconfig'
```

Был совет, что нужно установить python3-distutils

При запуске `sudo apt-get install python3-distutils` получаю

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package python3-distutils is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libpython3.6-stdlib:i386 libpython3.6-stdlib

E: Package 'python3-distutils' has no installation candidate
```

Поставил все зависимости которые указались выше

```
However the following packages replace it:
  libpython3.6-stdlib:i386 libpython3.6-stdlib
```

Ошибка все равно никак не решилась. Подскажите пожалуйста, как быть и что делать

Comment: что `/usr/bin/python3 -c 'from distutils import sysconfig'` команда выдаёт? и `apt-cache show $(apt-file find -F /usr/bin/python3 | awk -F: '{print $1}')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сегодня столкнулся с такой же проблемой. Скорее всего у тебя использовался.
`ppa:jonathonf/python-3.6`
Python 3.6.5 устанавливается, но во время выполнения get-pip.py ошибка.
Решилось изменением PPA.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3.6
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
sudo python3.6 get-pip.py
```

Answer (score 2):

попробуй это

```
sudo apt install python3-distutils
```

Мне помогло